# Populate DB Column for later registration without affecting current records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm working on re-modeling how users signup for my service and I believe I need to pre-populate my `Locations` table with some generated API keys.  The kicker is that I already have about 10 active customers using the same DB, so doing this through seeding would reset everything, which I can't do.

Right now, I have to do this through RailsAdmin to make a profile for an account:

1. Create a `Company`
2. Create a `Location` (this automatically inserts a generated hash for the Location_UID)
3. Create a `User`
4. Provision their device with the generated `Location_UID` and mail it to them

Instead, I'd like to have the following now:
 1. Customer buys their device (which already have the `Location_UID` provisioned as the Serial Number)
 2. Customer goes to the site to register their device and create a profile
 3. Customer creates a `User` account
 4. Customer adds a `Company`
 5. Customer adds a `Location` and registers their device to this location with the `Location_UID` they got with the device.

From here, the customer would be rocking and rolling!

I totally get that I'm going to have to rework my models, the dependencies and such, but the pre-generated `Location_UID` is my initial hangup (i think).

What would be the best way to add 1,000 more pre-generated `Location IDs` to my table without affecting the previous 10 that were created?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking... where are the existing locations currently stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the issue that you don't want to run `rake db:seed` on production? Could you just write a quick one time script to add the new Location IDs?

```
locations = #array of locations you want to add

locations.each { |location| Location.create(location) }
```

I don't see how adding more rows to the table would affect existing rows, but I could be misunderstanding the question.

Or if you auto-generate the ids and have no other info you need

```
1000.times { Location.create }
```

Comment: Usually in seeds, wherever possible, I do things like `first_or_create` to avoid duplication. Dunno if that's applicable here, but it's a thought

Comment: Yup, don't want to reseed the production DB and overwrite what's already there.  Script is easy to do.  It's amazing, sometimes I don't even think of the simplest solution!